# Datastore in Firestore mode - a distributed counter than can scale it's shards up based on traffic

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, sharding

In Datastore in Firestore mode the [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range) way to deal with storing a high write counter (such as profile views on a website) is to use sharded/distributed counters.

The problem I have is that with distributed counters you need to pick how many shards you want to have. This is addressed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters#limitations) as well. For example some profiles may get a lot more views per second than others (one profile may be a famous person while another is a regular person), and therefore need more shards.

Is there a way to write a distributed counter that can scale it's shards up if the page is getting a lot of views per second?

I was thinking of detecting a datastore contention error and then adding more shards if that happens.

I noticed there is a new [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-counter) for Cloud Firestore that seems to do what I am asking for. However, I am not using Cloud Firestore, I am using Datastore in Firestore mode - similar under the hood but still different.

Comment: I don't know if this would be a good solution, but have you considered using a pull queue?

Comment: @googlecloudsuportsucks Can you elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Datastore distributed counters example:

```
NUM_SHARDS = 20

class SimpleCounterShard(ndb.Model):
    """Shards for the counter"""
    count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)


def get_count():
    """Retrieve the value for a given sharded counter.

    Returns:
        Integer; the cumulative count of all sharded counters.
    """
    total = 0
    for counter in SimpleCounterShard.query():
        total += counter.count
    return total


@ndb.transactional
def increment():
    """Increment the value for a given sharded counter."""
    shard_string_index = str(random.randint(0, NUM_SHARDS - 1))
    counter = SimpleCounterShard.get_by_id(shard_string_index)
    if counter is None:
        counter = SimpleCounterShard(id=shard_string_index)
    counter.count += 1
    counter.put()
```

Used a fixed number of shards, but the [Firestore example](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters#python) uses a separate entity for keeping track of the number of shards.  So, you can update the code above with something like:

```
class RootCounter(ndb.Model):
  count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
  num_shards = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

  def get_count(self):
    if self.num_shards > 0:
      return sum([e.count for e in SimpleCounterShard.query(parent=self.key)])

    return count

  def increment(self):
    try:
      self._increment()
    except:
      self.num_shards += 1
      self.increment()
      self.put()

  @ndb.transactional(retries=1):
  def _increment(self):
    if self.num_shards > 0:
      SimpleCounterShard.increment(parent=self.key, self.num_shards)
    else:
      self.count += 1
      self.put()
```

The important difference since Firestore in Datastore mode has been released is that Firestore in Datastore mode is strongly consistent and that you are likely [not using entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore#transactions).  Thus a query will give an exact answer, and the sharded counters can nicely fit in the hierarchy with the root counter.

Comment: How would you be able to auto-detect that you need to add more shards? For example, maybe you started with 3 shards but writes aren't getting written due to contention and you need to add a few more shards.

Comment: As written, the code above will add shards (`except: self.num_shards += 1`) whenever a counter increment fails twice in a row (`@ndb.transactional(retries=1)`.

Comment: Is it a scalable solution to use transactions? Transactions can lock up the shards and be slow - especially in Firestore in Datastore mode. I'm wondering how this would perform if it had to scale from 10 shards to 200 shards within a few minutes.

Comment: You must use transactions for the counter increment for correctness.  The transition between sharded & unshared should also be transactional, that's a bug in the posted code.

Comment: The docs say "If your application receives an exception when committing a transaction, it does not always mean that the transaction failed. You can receive errors in cases where transactions have been committed. Whenever possible, make your transactions idempotent so that if you repeat a transaction, the end result will be the same." - doesn't that mean that this system might add a count twice even though it uses transactions? Because adding plus one to something isn't idempotent.